# Is there way to extract unique values from a comma seperated string value in Hive?

Tags: arrays, hive, unique

I want to extract unique values from a comma separated string value in a hive table.

As it is:

```
select * from data;
ID  ITEMS
123  "ABB","REG","REG", "ABB","XYZ"
```

Expected result:

```
select ===some logic=== from data;

ID  ITEMS
123  "ABB","REG","XYZ"
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explode` the csv values into one row per value by `split`ting the csv string and use `collect_set` on the split values to remove duplicates. The result would be an `array` and to get a csv value use `concat_ws`.

```
select id,items,concat_ws(',',collect_set(split_item)) as result
from data
lateral view explode(split(items,',')) tbl as split_item
group by id,items
```